# how to rename the crawler file with the search keyword in python icrawler

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, google-image-search

I am using crawler to download some images from google, but I find the download files are named with 000001.jpg, 000002.jpg. But what I except is that when the image downloads and at the same time change its name to the keyword(such as Coláiste Íosagáin,jpg, Mount Anville Secondary School.jpg, St Laurence College.jpg)

```
from icrawler.builtin import GoogleImageCrawler

google_crawler = GoogleImageCrawler(
    parser_threads=2,
    downloader_threads=4,
    storage={'root_dir': 'images'})

for keyword in ['Coláiste Íosagáin', 'Mount Anville Secondary School', 'St Laurence College']:
    google_crawler.crawl(
        keyword=keyword, max_num=1, min_size=(800, 800), max_size=(1200, 1200))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do this by overriding several of the classes to pass the keyword argument down to get_filename. This may not be the most direct way to do it, but it does work.

First, you need to override the Google Image Crawler's crawl method to pass in the keyword arg to the downloader. It's a lot of copy/paste for a one line addition:

```
from icrawler.builtin import GoogleImageCrawler
from icrawler import ImageDownloader
from PIL import Image
from six import BytesIO

class KeywordGoogleImageCrawler(GoogleImageCrawler):

    def crawl(self,
              keyword,
              filters=None,
              offset=0,
              max_num=1000,
              min_size=None,
              max_size=None,
              language=None,
              file_idx_offset=0,
              overwrite=False):
        if offset + max_num > 1000:
            if offset > 1000:
                self.logger.error(
                    '"Offset" cannot exceed 1000, otherwise you will get '
                    'duplicated searching results.')
                return
            elif max_num > 1000:
                max_num = 1000 - offset
                self.logger.warning(
                    'Due to Google\'s limitation, you can only get the first '
                    '1000 result. "max_num" has been automatically set to %d. '
                    'If you really want to get more than 1000 results, you '
                    'can specify different date ranges.', 1000 - offset)

        feeder_kwargs = dict(
            keyword=keyword,
            offset=offset,
            max_num=max_num,
            language=language,
            filters=filters)
        downloader_kwargs = dict(
            keyword=keyword,  #<<< add this line
            max_num=max_num,
            min_size=min_size,
            max_size=max_size,
            file_idx_offset=file_idx_offset,
            overwrite=overwrite)
        super(GoogleImageCrawler, self).crawl(
            feeder_kwargs=feeder_kwargs, downloader_kwargs=downloader_kwargs)
```

Then, you need to override the Downloader class to:

1. update get_filename to accept keyword as a parameter
2. update get_filename to include the keyword in the filename
3. update keep_file to include a **kwargs parameter so you don't get an "unexpected keyword argument" error
4. update the download method to pass in the keyword to the calls to get_filename

`class KeywordNameDownloader(ImageDownloader):`

```
def get_filename(self, task, default_ext, keyword):
    filename = super(KeywordNameDownloader, self).get_filename(
        task, default_ext)
    return keyword + filename

def keep_file(self, task, response, min_size=None, max_size=None, **kwargs):
    """Decide whether to keep the image

    Compare image size with ``min_size`` and ``max_size`` to decide.

    Args:
        response (Response): response of requests.
        min_size (tuple or None): minimum size of required images.
        max_size (tuple or None): maximum size of required images.
    Returns:
        bool: whether to keep the image.
    """
    try:
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    except (IOError, OSError):
        return False
    task['img_size'] = img.size
    if min_size and not self._size_gt(img.size, min_size):
        return False
    if max_size and not self._size_lt(img.size, max_size):
        return False
    return True

def download(self,
             task,
             default_ext,
             timeout=5,
             max_retry=3,
             overwrite=False,
             **kwargs):
    """Download the image and save it to the corresponding path.

    Args:
        task (dict): The task dict got from ``task_queue``.
        timeout (int): Timeout of making requests for downloading images.
        max_retry (int): the max retry times if the request fails.
        **kwargs: reserved arguments for overriding.
    """
    file_url = task['file_url']
    task['success'] = False
    task['filename'] = None
    retry = max_retry
    keyword = kwargs['keyword']

    if not overwrite:
        with self.lock:
            self.fetched_num += 1
            filename = self.get_filename(task, default_ext,keyword)
            if self.storage.exists(filename):
                self.logger.info('skip downloading file %s', filename)
                return
            self.fetched_num -= 1

    while retry > 0 and not self.signal.get('reach_max_num'):
        try:
            response = self.session.get(file_url, timeout=timeout)
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error('Exception caught when downloading file %s, '
                              'error: %s, remaining retry times: %d',
                              file_url, e, retry - 1)
        else:
            if self.reach_max_num():
                self.signal.set(reach_max_num=True)
                break
            elif response.status_code != 200:
                self.logger.error('Response status code %d, file %s',
                                  response.status_code, file_url)
                break
            elif not self.keep_file(task, response, **kwargs):
                break
            with self.lock:
                self.fetched_num += 1
                filename = self.get_filename(task, default_ext,keyword)
            self.logger.info('image #%s\t%s', self.fetched_num, file_url)
            self.storage.write(filename, response.content)
            task['success'] = True
            task['filename'] = filename
            break
        finally:
            retry -= 1
```

After all that, you can run something like this:

```
google_crawler = KeywordGoogleImageCrawler(downloader_cls=KeywordNameDownloader, storage={'root_dir': 'image_downloads'})
google_crawler.crawl(keyword='cat', max_num=4)
```

and get an output like this:

```
 Directory of C:\<my local path>\image_downloads

12/09/2019  09:57 AM    <DIR>          .
12/09/2019  09:57 AM    <DIR>          ..
12/09/2019  09:57 AM         1,246,129 cat000001.png
12/09/2019  09:57 AM         2,627,334 cat000002.jpg
12/09/2019  09:57 AM           127,213 cat000003.jpg
12/09/2019  09:57 AM           789,779 cat000004.jpg
```